# problem when using the command rospack depends1

Tags: ros, python, rospy, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everybody, I'm a newbie to ROS groovy as well as Ubuntu. I'm trying to follow up the ROS tutorials, and when I've com to this ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage when trying to find out the dependency of the package I've just created using command **rospack depends1 Beginner std_msgs roscpp rospy** which Beginner is my pack name, it showed the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 107, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 501, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 419, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/edmond/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 55, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 107, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 501, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 419, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/edmond/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[rospack] Error: could not call python function 'rosdep2.rospack.init_rospack_interface'
```

I think the problem goes with some python related files, but I've also tried not including rospy for my package, it remains the same error.
Does anyone know what could possibly be the reason?
Thanks a lot

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 right now

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53893/problem-when-using-the-command-rospack-depends1/) by [edmond320](https://answers.ros.org/users/4100/edmond320/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-01-31**:
Can you run `$ dpkg -p ros-groovy-rospack` and share the result? You can paste the result to your original question by click "Edit". Also, please always tell us which ROS distro (e.g. Groovy / Fuerte).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you ran some command using sudo, which you should not have, and now you have read-protected files in '/home/edmond/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'.

Remove all files in /home/edmond/.ros, using sudo if necessary. Then, don't use sudo commands anymore for any ros command. If you believe that a ros command only works with calling sudo, you are doing something wrong.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [satr](https://answers.ros.org/users/19917/satr/) on 2014-08-05**:
I installed ros-groovy-ros-base for ARM on pcDuino and created package from tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage. On error - commands: sudo chmod +R 777 ~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index or deleting all from ~/.ros - did not help. Could you tell what else should I look at?